# In R, if I have an RData file under "arg_233_1_3.RData", how can I call it just by specifying "arg"?

Tags: r, regex

In `R`, I currently have a lot of folders, and in each folder, I have a different `.RData` file. Each `RData` file has a different name, but always starts with `"arg"`. For example, `"arg_233_1_1.RData"`, `"arg_233_1_2.RData"`, etc.

Is there a way to load in these files just by using regular expressions, etc, just by calling out `'arg'`?

For example, this doesn't work:

```
load("arg*.RData")
```

but is there something of this flavor that works? Thanks.

Comment: Use `list.files()` to "grob" for similarly named files. Then apply those strings to `load()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tools that will help, based on @MrFlick's comment:

- `list.files(pattern="^arg.*\\.RData")` will return all files in the current directory that match the pattern. These patterns follow *regex* rules, not normal file-globbing rules.
- `list.files(pattern="^arg.*\\.RData", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)` will do the same thing but look in the current (or `path=...`) directory and all descendent directories. The `full.names` is so that the full path is included, otherwise it will return just file names, not the whole path.

Once you know how to find them, you can load them all programmatically with one of the following:

```
ign <- sapply(list.files(pattern="^TEX.*up.png$"), load)
```

The above should load all into the global environment. This might be good (if all variables within all of them are unique), but might also silently overwrite variables as well.

A slightly safer option would be to load them into captive lists/environments:

```
full_of_arg <- sapply(list.files(pattern="^TEX.*up.png$"),
                      function(fn) { e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv()); load(fn, envir=e); e; },
                      simplify=FALSE)
```

will return a `list` of `environment`s, which is generally good enough. For this, you can do `full_of_arg[[1]]$varname` to get a variable named `varname` within the first arg file. The names (`names(full_of_arg)`) will tell you from which file the variables were pulled.

Accessing an `environment` is effectively the same as accessing `list`s, and though there are some minor differences (e.g., cannot index by position; that is `e <- new.env(); e[[1]]` does not work), you should be fine. If you really must have embedded lists, you can use `as.list(e)`. (A couple of other accessor mechanisms listed https://gist.github.com/hadley/5434786.)